# ggplot Barplot Change size of ONE bar only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a very simple barplot with ggplot with multiple factors. One of the factor is missing (so cannot be plotted as I just don't have any data for it), no big deal but it leads to one of the bar being way bigger than the others.

Is there any way to either reduce the size of this particular bar or just avoid plotting it bigger from the start?

```
ggplot(data=tgc, aes(x=caste, y=dct,fill=treatment)) +  
  geom_col(width=0.7,position=position_dodge(width=0.8)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=dct-se, ymax=dct+se),width=.2,position=position_dodge(.8))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("orangered2", "dodgerblue"))+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      axis.title.x=element_blank(),
      axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image: Bar Q is way bigger due to the fact that there are no Q - QL data available]

Comment: Read about the `preserve` argument in `?position_dodge`

Comment: Use the `preserve = "single"` argument in `position_dodge`

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes this was exactly what I was looking for. I agree this is probably a duplicate question, I never found this link!

Comment: BTW for those who don't know, it seems that position_dodge2 is better and preserve the bar centre location

Answer (score 0):

Transform it before you plot it. If you apply a log on the measurement variable, the differences among the plots will be reduced.